# Input live check

Tags: javascript, input, live

i got a input field and a button

```
<input required id="solution" name="solution" type="text" placeholder=""class="form-control input-md">
<button style="background-color:#da251d;" id="sendForm" name="sendForm" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
```

Now i want to check the input Field for an value, when the value is incorrect, the button should be disbaled, i try it with js like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(“#solution”).keyup(function(){
            if($(this).val() == ‘value’) {
                $(‘#sendForm’).attr(‘disabled’,‘disabled);
            }
            else {
                $(‘#sendForm’).removeattr(‘disabled’);
            }
        });
});
```

But it dont work, can you help me pls?

Comment: use `removeAttr()` not `removeattr` !

Comment: Are you aware  that your source code is using `jQuery`  and will require you to load the `jQuery` library into your page? No `jQuery` tagged with your question so wasn't sure if you were aware of it. Also, open your browser console and check for errors. If you see something like `$` is not defined then the chances are you haven't loaded in the library.

Comment: And for the _quotes_, use `'  '` or `"   "`, not `‘  ’` .

Answer (score 0):

Easy one!

The code does not work since you're using **quotation marks (”)** but what you should be using are the **String marks** (**"** or **'**).
The working code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#solution").keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'value') {
            $('#sendForm').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        else {
            $('#sendForm').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

[Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zomiralovo/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

i think you did the typo error on .removeAttr

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#solution").keyup(function(){
            if($(this).val() == "value") {
                $("#sendForm").attr("disabled","disabled");
            }
            else {
                $("#sendForm").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the "change" or the "input" event. It would look similar to

```
$('#solution').on('change', function(){
  // validation & toggle button state
})
```

For further event documentations:
[change](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: But by making the changes you have suggested isn't going to fix the problem is it...  so this isn't a solution or answering why the current source code isn't functioning as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is working fine ,

```
$("#solution").keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'value') {
            $('#sendForm').attr('disabled',false);
        }
        else {
            $('#sendForm').attr('disabled',true);
        }
    });
```

You can use attr method for setting disabled property as true or false as per your need.

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3agabrf9/)